# how to get current URL of IE using add in express

Tags: visual-studio, addin-express

I am developing addon for IE using add-in express. I need a way to get current url of IE in this development environment. Is there anyone who knows about this? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [blog](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2008/03/14/ie-addons-toolbars-menus-programming/). In the comment section is the answer:

> There is no way to access it dynamically. Instead you can use the LocationName and LocationURL property of the IEApp to get the current URL address.